Event handling for encapsulated socket.io server
I (js beginner) am creating a node.js webapp with socket.io. I encapsulated my socket server and namespaces to a single module that I call socketManager.js because I heard that this is generally good practice. This module handles everything sockets for my backend like initialization and exports of series of functions to provide limited access to socket functionality. This works great when I want the server to emit an event in particular. However, I have found that while dealing with events originate in socketManager (client event emissions) I cannot access other files or invoke their functionality. I cannot import custom modules into socketManger as most of them import socketManger - and doing so would result in dependency errors. Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I taking the wrong approach?
Some code snippets for context:
socketManager.js:
```
//import things
//IIFE/singleton to init
const socketManager = (() => {
    let chatIO;
    //initialize socket server
    function initializeSocketServers(server, sessionMiddleware) {
        //init logic (logic, innit)
        };
        // Initialize chatIO namespace

    // Handler for chatIO namespace
    const chatHandler = (socket) => {
        socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
        //more chat functions
        });

        socket.on('joinRoom', room => {
        //join room
        });

        socket.on('leaveRoom', room => {
            //leave room
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        //handle disconnect
        });
    };

    const joinChat = (socketId, room) => {
        //calls join room, works good
    }

    const leaveChat = (socketId, room) => {
        //calls leave room, works good
    }

    const checkInComplete = (matchID) => {
        //sends data to users, works good
    }

    return {
        initializeSocketServers,
        joinChat,
        leaveChat,
        checkInComplete,
        checkInFailure,
    };
})();


module.exports = socketManager;
```

An example of a case I am struggling with is a check-in process I am trying to implement with sockets. The gist of it is a user checks-in, which emits an event to the server, which the socket server receives. It then needs to pass the user data onto a check-in handling function, the only problem is, it's in a different module. The event handler should look like this:
'''
socket.on('checkIn', socket=>{
    //check in handling logic, including data available in another file
});
'''

